# Scroller function of angular-datatables in md-tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, angular-material, angular-datatables

I have been searching for many hours but I couldn't fine useful answer. Please help me fix this problem.

Problem: I inserted angular-datatables in md-tab (Angular material).
Everything worked fine until I added scrollY or scrollX option. The tables didn't show any content when I added the scroller option.
Here is the code

```
 <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-selected="msWizard.selectedIndex" md-center-tabs="true">
                <md-tab>
                    <md-tab-label>
                        <span>Product</span>
                    </md-tab-label>

                    <md-tab-body>
<table class="dataTable row-border hover" datatable="ng" dt-instance="vm.dtInstance"
                   dt-options="vm.dtOptions">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="secondary-text">
                            <div class="table-header">
                                <span class="column-title">ID</span>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="secondary-text">
                            <div class="table-header">
                                <span class="column-title">Image</span>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="secondary-text">
                            <div class="table-header">
                                <span class="column-title">Name</span>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="secondary-text">
                            <div class="table-header">
                                <span class="column-title">Category</span>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="secondary-text">
                            <div class="table-header">
                                <span class="column-title">Price</span>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="secondary-text">
                            <div class="table-header">
                                <span class="column-title">Quantity</span>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="secondary-text">
                            <div class="table-header">
                                <span class="column-title">Active</span>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="secondary-text">
                            <div class="table-header">
                                <span class="column-title">Actions</span>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="product in ::vm.products">
                        <td>{{product.id}}</td>
                        <td><img class="product-image" ng-src="{{product.image}}"></td>
                        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.category}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.price}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
                        <td>{{product.active}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <md-button class="edit-button md-icon-button" ng-click="vm.gotoProductDetail(product.id)" aria-label="Product details"
                                       translate translate-attr-aria-label="EC.PRODUCT_DETAILS">
                                <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-pencil" class="s16"></md-icon>
                            </md-button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and here is my js function

```
 vm.dtOptions = {
        dom         : 'rt<"bottom"<"left"<"length"l>><"right"<"info"i><"pagination"p>>>',
        columnDefs  : [
             {

                targets: 0,
                width  : '10px'
            },
             {

                targets: 1,
                width  : '20px'
            },
            {

                targets: 2,
                width  : '72px'
            },
            {

                targets: 3,
                width  : '72px'
            },
            {

                targets: 4,
                width  : '72px'
            },
            {

                targets: 5,
                width  : '72px'
            },
            {

                targets: 6,
                width  : '72px'
            },
            {

                targets: 7,
                width  : '72px'
            },
            {

                targets: 8,
                width  : '72px'
            },

        ],
        pagingType: 'simple',
        autoWidth : false,
        pageLength  : 20,
        scrollY    : 'auto', //This line makes a problem
        responsive  : true,


    };
```

This code works fine for me when I use it outside md-tab. 
How can I fix this problem. Can anyone help me?
By the way, I have already include "datatables" and "datatables.scroller" followed the example.

Comment: "_The problem is the table is collapsed so every rows in the table are rendered in the same line_". OK, thought a `rerender()` would solve that problem. Deleted the answer. You could try out `vm.dtInstance.DataTable.columns.adjust()` instead, and see what happens ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To test your method, I added "refresh button" to my table and I clicked on it when the page showed. It would call function followed this:
`function tabSelected(){
   vm.dtInstance.DataTable.columns.adjust();
   vm.dtInstance.rerender();
  }`

The problem seems not to be solved. Moreover, the head column disappeared.

Comment: Even worse. Weird. Can you set up a plunkr? Here is one with dataTables, I dont know how easy it is to add angular material -> http://plnkr.co/edit/nBtzURQxSgKIqFvGMkWC?p=preview

Comment: I have set the plunkr as you request but it is a little bit weird. The datatables did not function properly. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/1FqeeQvIvEnHxpF3okjH?p=preview
BTW, main content that I want to show is inserted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have solution. The solution is very easy. As I have mentioned, the table showed data correctly in html code but it didn't appear in the page so I just only set height property as followed.

```
 <div style="height: 700px;"   layout="column" flex>
    <table class="dataTable row-border hover" datatable="ng" dt-instance="vm.dtInstance" dt-options="vm.dtOptions">
...
```